# Shouldn't "decursus" be accusative in Psalm 1:3?

Tags: grammar-choice, vulgata

> (Psalm 1:3, Clementine Vulgate) Et erit tamquam lignum quod plantatum est secus decursus aquarum, quod fructum suum dabit in tempore suo: et folium ejus non defluet; et omnia quæcumque faciet prosperabuntur.

The Douay-Rheims translates this into English as, "And he shall be like a tree which is planted near the running waters . . ."

How should *decursus* be parsed in this verse?

According to Wiktionary, *secus* is a preposition taking an accusative, but *decursus* doesn't look like it is in accusative form to me. What am I missing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The noun *decursus* belongs to the fourth declension, not the second. You know this because, if you look it up in a dictionary, the two forms that are given (the 'principal parts') will be *dēcursus*, *-ūs*, not *dēcursus*, *-ī*. Therefore, in your passage, *decursus* is, in fact, accusative, but plural (= *dēcursūs*).

Comment: Oh, I see now! When I looked up *decursus* on Wiktionary, it was listed as a participle form of the verb *decurro*. I didn't know it was also a noun.